# javascript random var array image

Tags: javascript

I have the following code:

> ```
> <script src="js/jquery-1.8.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
> <script src="js/html5placeholder.jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
>
> <!--[if IE]><script type="text/javascript" src="js/excanvas.js"> </script><![endif]-->
> <script src="js/general.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
> <script language="JavaScript"> 
> function foo(n)
> {
>     var a = 123456789;
>     a = a.toString();
>     var result = "";
>     e = document.getElementById("kq");
>     for(i = 0; i < a.length; i++)
>     {
>         result += "<img src=\"number/a"+a[i]+".png\" />";
>
>     }
>     e.innerHTML = result;
>
> }
>
>
> var solanMax = 10;
> var n = 0;
> function foo2()
> {
>         solan = 0;
>         result = "";
>         result += "<img src=\"number/a"+n+".png\" />";
>         if(n == 9)
>             n -= 9;
>         if(n >= 0)
>             n++;
>         e0 = document.getElementById("kq0");
>          e1 = document.getElementById("kq1");
>           e2 = document.getElementById("kq2");
>            e3 = document.getElementById("kq3");
>             e4 = document.getElementById("kq4");
>              e5 = document.getElementById("kq5");
>               e6 = document.getElementById("kq6");
>                e7 = document.getElementById("kq7");
>                 e8 = document.getElementById("kq8");
>                  e9 = document.getElementById("kq9");
>
>         e0.innerHTML = result;
>         e1.innerHTML = result;
>         e2.innerHTML = result;
>         e3.innerHTML = result;
>         e4.innerHTML = result;
>         e5.innerHTML = result;
>         e6.innerHTML = result;
>         e7.innerHTML = result;
>         e8.innerHTML = result;
>         e9.innerHTML = result;
>         solan ++;
>         T = setTimeout('foo2('+n+')',solan); 
> }
> function Stop(){
> setTimeout('clearTimeout(T)',1000);
>
> }
> </script> 
> <input type=button value='Lottery Number Picker' onClick="foo2();"> 
> <span id="kq0" class=a1>Result</span> 
> <span id="kq1" class=a1>Result</span> 
> <span id="kq2" class=a1>Result</span> 
> <span id="kq3" class=a1>Result</span> 
> <span id="kq4" class=a1>Result</span> 
> <span id="kq5" class=a1>Result</span> 
> <span id="kq6" class=a1>Result</span> 
> <span id="kq7" class=a1>Result</span> 
> <span id="kq8" class=a1>Result</span> 
> <span id="kq9" class=a1>Result</span> 
> <br>
> <input type=button value='Stop' onClick="Stop();">
> ```

I want to press the "Stop" button, the number of that returns is the same for all the presets
Demo: http://group-cast.com/Binhchon/test.php
thank you very much, I'm Vietnamese so I'm a bit bad at english

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what exactly you want. But as you are generating numbers for a lottery ticket, I assume you want the numbers to be random. You may add a new function `getImageForRandomNum` and change the `foo2` function like this...

```
function getImageForRandomNum(){
      var n = Math.floor((Math.random() * 10));
      result = "<img src=\"number/a"+n+".png\" />";
      return result;
}

function foo2()
{
        e0 = document.getElementById("kq0");
         e1 = document.getElementById("kq1");
          e2 = document.getElementById("kq2");
           e3 = document.getElementById("kq3");
            e4 = document.getElementById("kq4");
             e5 = document.getElementById("kq5");
              e6 = document.getElementById("kq6");
               e7 = document.getElementById("kq7");
                e8 = document.getElementById("kq8");
                 e9 = document.getElementById("kq9");

        e0.innerHTML = getImageForRandomNum();
        e1.innerHTML = getImageForRandomNum();
        e2.innerHTML = getImageForRandomNum();
        e3.innerHTML = getImageForRandomNum();
        e4.innerHTML = getImageForRandomNum();
        e5.innerHTML = getImageForRandomNum();
        e6.innerHTML = getImageForRandomNum();
        e7.innerHTML = getImageForRandomNum();
        e8.innerHTML = getImageForRandomNum();
        e9.innerHTML = getImageForRandomNum();
        solan ++;
        T = setTimeout('foo2('+n+')',solan); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you have jquery on the page I would change your span html to this

```
<span id="kq0" class="a1"><img src="" alt="" class="randomNum"></span> 
<span id="kq1" class="a1"><img src="" alt="" class="randomNum"></span> 
<span id="kq2" class="a1"><img src="" alt="" class="randomNum"></span> 
<span id="kq3" class="a1"><img src="" alt="" class="randomNum"></span> 
<span id="kq4" class="a1"><img src="" alt="" class="randomNum"></span> 
<span id="kq5" class="a1"><img src="" alt="" class="randomNum"></span> 
<span id="kq6" class="a1"><img src="" alt="" class="randomNum"></span> 
<span id="kq7" class="a1"><img src="" alt="" class="randomNum"></span> 
<span id="kq8" class="a1"><img src="" alt="" class="randomNum"></span> 
<span id="kq9" class="a1"><img src="" alt="" class="randomNum"></span>
```

Then change your foo2 function to this

```
function foo2() {

   $(".randomNum").each(function(){
      var ran = Math.floor(Math.random() * 9 + 1);
      var img = "number/a" + ran + ".png";
      $(this).attr('src', img);
   });
   T = setTimeout(foo2, 500);
}
```